# How to solve "Failed to load config "airbnb-typescript" to extend from." on Google Cloud Build?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, eslint, google-cloud-build

TL;DR, the error:

```
Step #0: Creating an optimized production build...
Step #0: Failed to compile.
Step #0: 
Step #0: Failed to load config "airbnb-typescript" to extend from.
Step #0: Referenced from: /app/.eslintrc.js
```

I am trying to build a frontend project with Tailwind CSS, Craco and React, with Docker. I have a similar project running, only without Tailwind and Craco, but with the same eslint settings, which is not giving any problems.

I am running a DockerFile on Google Cloud Build, which is failing on .eslintrc.js . Locally, the DockerFile is running without any problems, same as running npm run build script locally.
I can not find any information about this error on Cloud build, so hopefully someone knows how to solve this.

I also have pushed the Dockerfile I build locally to Container Images on Google Cloud, but also no success.

When I delete the `"airbnb-typescript"` from the `extends` array in `.eslintrc.js`, it will throw the same error, only with the next package in the `extends` array, which is `'airbnb/hooks'` in this case.

This is the part of the error log on Google Cloud Build:

```
Step #0: Step 9/14 : RUN npm run build
Step #0:  ---> Running in 4a21e90bac22
Step #0: 
Step #0: > react-tailwind-frontend@0.1.0 build /app
Step #0: > craco build
Step #0: 
Step #0: Creating an optimized production build...
Step #0: Failed to compile.
Step #0: 
Step #0: Failed to load config "airbnb-typescript" to extend from.
Step #0: Referenced from: /app/.eslintrc.js
Step #0: 
Step #0: 
Step #0: [91mnpm[0m[91m ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Step #0: [0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91mERR! [0m[91merrno 1
Step #0: [0m[91mnpm ERR! react-tailwind-frontend@0.1.0 build: `craco build`
Step #0: npm ERR! Exit status 1
Step #0: npm ERR! 
Step #0: [0m[91mnpm ERR! Failed at the react-tailwind-frontend@0.1.0 build script.
Step #0: npm [0m[91mERR![0m[91m This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Step #0: [0m[91m
Step #0: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #0: npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-15T07_41_43_989Z-debug.log
Step #0: The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #0
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
Step #0: [0m
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-tailwind-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.10",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.16",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.18",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml --watch -r dotenv/config",
    "dev": "craco start",
    "dev:all": "REACT_APP_REMOTE_URL=http://localhost:4001 npm-run-all -p dev codegen -c -l",
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.ts{,x}\"",
    "lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint -c ./.eslintrc.js  \"**/*.ts{,x}\" --fix"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "1.20.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/introspection": "1.18.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "1.21.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "1.17.14",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "2.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.15.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^3.10.1",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": "eslint --cache --fix",
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": "prettier --write"
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile.**
So, it fails at npm run build:

```
FROM node:14-alpine as frontend-builder

ARG REACT_APP_REMOTE_URL
ARG REACT_APP_WS_URL

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json /app/

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN npm install

COPY ./ /app

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=frontend-builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/react',
  ],
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint', 'react-hooks'],
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect', // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
    },
  },
  rules: {
    'linebreak-style': 'off',
  },
};
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you but could you show us the tree of the folder from where you're executing this? Just to get a bit of a clearer picture on how you're loading your files onto the docker. Considering it builds fine locally, I'd imagine it might be something failing to import or one of the odd quirks of Cloud Build, but everything I say is guesswork unless I ask questions

Comment: See my answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67364108/react-app-failed-to-load-config-airbnb-in-deploying-to-heroku/67891398#67891398), had to use a production only environment variable `DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true` to bypass this webpack issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly an issue with React js application and has nothing to do with Cloud Build setup.

You are running https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco which in turn runs eslint. You have dependency on `airbnb-typescript` eslint configuration but seems you have not installed it. You have listed `eslint-config-airbnb-typescript` as devDependency, but you didn’t installed dev dependencies.
Again craco runs eslint which is configured to use dependency which is only installed as development dependency and but have not installed development dependencies. Make sure that "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript" is in their regular dependencies or install dev dependencies before running craco.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple possibilities and causes for this error. I am listing some of them for you to look, analyse and try upon.

1. Add the typescript plugin to .eslintrc, using the [extends option in
   .eslintrc](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import#typescript)

   ```
   extends: [
    "plugin:import/errors", 
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    ],
   ```
2. You need to install this package:

   ```
   yarn add -D eslint-import-resolver-typescript
   ```

   Then add this to your .eslintrc.js file or .eslintrc.json
   configuration file:

   ```
       { 
   ... settings: { 
   ...
   'import/resolver': {
    node: { 
              extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'], 
              moduleDirectory: ['node_modules', 'src/'], 
   },
      },
          } 
            }
   ```
3. As per this [GitHub solution](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9887#issuecomment-772741743), the issue can be fixed by :

   Creating  .env file and include :

   ```
   SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
   ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true
   ```

   Creating .env.production file and include :

   ```
   SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
   DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true
   PUBLIC_URL=/my-app
   ```
4. Add these two lines in package.json under "scripts" by removing the current "lint" and replacing it with `"lint": "eslint . src/ --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx", "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix"`. Also check this [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript) to see if you have to include `'airbnb','airbnb-typescript','airbnb-base','airbnb-typescript/base'` in "extends" field in ESlint config file depending on your case

   Have a look at each of the references below, as there are multiple
   solutions proposed to this issue and can help you look and analyse
   at the various alternatives and how others solved it.

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9887
- https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import#typescript
- https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin

Comment: Hi @Priyashree, thanks for taking time to explain.
Unfortunately, none of the options are working...

Comment: I now added the .env.production and disabled eslint on production. But still, don't think this is the way to go. 
But already spent hours / days to solve it.

Comment: @Royal were you able to finally solve this issue or do you still need help on this?

Comment: @Royal If you were able to solve, please post the solution as an answer, so that community members can refer your solution if they have a similar issue. Kindly post the answer. I will acknowledge it.

Comment: All of the above didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: So that means, you are still stuck with the issue and you need help to resolve it? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, still not working indeed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I will be helping you again with this question. I want you to try two things now : 1. Add these two lines in package.json under "scripts" by removing the current "lint" and replacing it with "lint": "eslint . src/ --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix". Also check this [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript) to see if you have to include 'airbnb','airbnb-typescript','airbnb-base','airbnb-typescript/base' in "extends" field in ESlint config file depending on your case.

Comment: @Royal did it help you? Please cooperate and respond so that we can solve your issue at the earliest.

Answer (score -1):

I have recently built the tailwind-css example from the MUI repo.  I got a successful compilation by moving the tailwind-css directory of its own, outside of MUI.  Hopefully someone reading this finds it helpful.